# How to ask for reference from a non-academic acquaintance?

Tags: reference-request

I have a non-academic acquaintance who is at a senior position in the telecom industry. He might have good links in academia. I am thinking to ask him for suggesting or referring me to his contacts in academia for a post-doctoral position. I do not want any favor based on nepotism or anything like that, just a chance of getting my CV noticed.

I am confused about it being ethical or not. Maybe I am being too eager.

How can I approach my acquaintance about this without giving 'him' the feeling that I want his favor or that I want to use his name?

PS. It is about North American institutes.

Comment: There is nothing unethical about asking.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I approach my acquaintance about this without giving 'him' the feeling that I want his favor or that I want to use his name?

You do want his favor and name, but that's fine: If he helps, then he is doing so because he wants to.

Answer (score -1):

You ask nicely, and by wanting his name to push your cv forward you want his favor and support.

So, realise what you are asking and respect that.